# asp grid view hyperlink field not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a logLink column in my database.
I have my hyperlink field in gridView as below :

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="logLink" DataTextField="logLink" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" Text="Link"  ControlStyle-CssClass="hlink" HeaderText="LOG LINK" ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" />
```

But this link is not clickable.

I want the values in the log link column of my db to come here.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: DataNavigateUrlFormatString is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong in that ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539667/how-to-bind-the-url-of-a-gridview-hyperlinkfield-when-the-bound-value-contains-a

Comment: My requirement is that I just want to go to a link where link=value in LogLink column

Comment: you can also use `asp:HyperLink` in templatefield.

Comment: @Manish - <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="hlink" HeaderText="LOG LINK" ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEditTxn" NavigateUrl='Try1.aspx'
                        Text="Link" runat="server" ></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Okay now how do I change "Try1.aspx" to value of logLink field ?? I tried adding a DataTextField

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnk" runat="server" Target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("yourText") %>'
                NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("logLink") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: OnClick nothing is happening but the link comes down in the browser window but it doesn't direct there

Comment: When i say it comes down in the browser window i meant that when i point my arrow to the Link,the select arrow changes to the hand arrow and in the browser in the bottom i can see my link data but it is not directing there on clicking.

Comment: how about trying href of that hyperlink

Comment: @dazzling- u mean url ?

Comment: Whe i type the url directly in the browser in a new tab it opens,so there is no problem with that

Comment: Manish u understood my ques ?

Comment: @user1698232 means you want postback on click event and pass querystring value from code behind?

Comment: No,I just want it to go to url where url=value of logLink

Comment: @user1698232 means you want to write if condition on `loglink`.